# How to display the Visual Studio 2013 icon color chart?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

Win7, Visual Studio 2013:  After creating an icon with the following steps ... Open Resources.resx => Add Resource => Add New Icon ... it displays an icon.  However the color chart is missing (the color chart for Brush Tool, etc.).

Opening an old wpf program, that displays the color chart.

What action needs to be taken to display the Visual Studio 2013 icon color chart?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite subtle.  Right click next to icon ... select Show Colors Window.